# React hooks: onValueChanged execute twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have the following problem on react hooks:

In `onValueChanged` of a `SelectBox`:

```
<Item
  dataField="student"
  editorType="dxSelectBox"
  editorOptions={{
    items: students,
    displayExpr: "name",
    valueExpr:"id", onValueChanged:onChange}}
></Item>
```

I call this method:

```js
const onChange = (event) => {
  console.log("value>>>",event.value)
  setValue(event.value)
}
```

I declare the state like:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
```

The problem is that the `onChange` method is called once when the selection of the selectbox changes. But when performing the `setValue`, for some reason the `onChange` method is called again and the saved value is lost, also `event.value` does not have a value:

[image: it shows the following]

i would really appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: This is interesting.  Perhaps you could set up an example to play with, like a codesandbox?  It would help in debugging.

Comment: React doesn't have a `SelectBox`.

Comment: Can you include more code, like the `Item` component and the containing component, and where the onChange method is declared?

Comment: I'm using the devextreme library: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Form/CustomizeItem/React/Light/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed it with DevExtreme <Switch... />. The problem is that if the input depends on useState value, when you set the state the control registers it as another change. Test if the event value is not the same as current state before changing the state [**status !== e.value**]

```
const handleStatusChange = (e) => {
    if (status !== e.value) {
        setStatus(e.value);
        console.log(e.value);
    };
}
```

Comment: For `Switch` I had to use `defaultValue` for some reason, even with a controlled component. For `SelectBox`, what a headache this became with Select-All functionality, where the Select-All checkbox state has to reflect whether or not the others are all checked. Setting values programatically was causing events everywhere!

Comment: Actually, even `defaultValue` behaves oddly for `Switch`. `value` with `onValueChange` instead of `onValueChanged` seems to do what I want now.